# Updating text in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to update the text in my JFrame using the `show()` method.
The only thing is it isn't working. The text is supposed to be changed because I can print it out, but the frame doesn't change the text unless I make a new frame. Does anyone know what's up?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
    
public class TetrisViewer {
    private Board gameBoard;
    private BoardToTextConverter textConverter;

    public TetrisViewer(Board board) {
        this.gameBoard = board;
        this.textConverter = new BoardToTextConverter();
    }

    public void show() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tetris");
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(gameBoard.getHeight(),gameBoard.getWidth());
        String stringBoard = textConverter.convertToText(gameBoard);
        textArea.setText(stringBoard);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN, 20));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void update(Board updBoard) {
         JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(updBoard.getHeight(),updBoard.getWidth());
         String stringBoard = textConverter.convertToText(updBoard);
         textArea.setText(stringBoard);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Don't create a new JTextArea** - your update method creates a new JTextArea but you never add it to the frame. Instead pass the text area as a parameter to your method. Actually you really should start over as your class is poorly structured. Take a look at the example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use a Text Area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). It show how to keep appending text to a text area.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong field. Instead of creating new object:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(updBoard.getHeight(),updBoard.getWidth());  //remove this
```

simply do:

```
textArea.setText(stringBoard);
```